# Simple Login form getting a "An unhandled exception"

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a simple login form that connects to the login data table, but I am getting a error when I debug.

This is my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace KEBMS
{
    public partial class frmWelcome : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\Project\KEBMS\KEBMS\MainDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        SqlCommand Com;
        public frmWelcome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {



            String Username, Password;
            con.Open();
            String sql = "SELECT [username],[Password] FROM tblLogin WHERE (Username='" + txtusername.Text + "' Password='" + txtpassword.Text + "')";
            Com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = Com.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();

            Username = dr["Username"].ToString();
            Password = dr["Password"].ToString();





            if (txtusername.Text == Username && txtpassword.Text == Password)
            {
                frmHome Home = new frmHome();
                Home.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username and Password");
                txtusername.Clear();
                txtpassword.Clear();
                txtusername.Focus();


            }

            con.Close();

        }
        private void btnexit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

and the error is:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'Password'."

I am still very new to `C#`, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Post the error text, please.

Comment: Hi , it's 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'Password'.

Answer (score 0):

Put the con in a try catch block and it will specify better what the problem is.

Comment: Hi . Can you give me a example of where to add the Try catch , I have been Trying to add them but ran into errors every time . 
Would appreciate it .

Comment: string error = "";
        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            error+= e;
            throw;
        }

Answer (score 0):

The *immediate cause* of the exception is that `password` is a *keyword* and that's why should be put in brackets: `where ... [Password] = ...`.

However, there are *too many* problems in the implementation; so let's rewrite it from start:

Model:

```
   private static string ConnectionString {
     get {
       //TODO: do not hardcode. move it to settings
       return @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=D:\Project\KEBMS\KEBMS\MainDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
     }
   }
```

Business logic (Controller):

```
   //DONE: method extracted
   private bool TryLogin(string login, string password) {
     //DONE: do not use global connections
     //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
       con.Open();

       //DONE: Make Sql readable
       //DONE: Make Sql parametrized
       //DONE: Do not expose password - SELECT 1 
       //TODO: Do not store password as a plain text, but its hash      
       string sql = 
         @"SELECT 1 -- we don't want to return any login/password  
             FROM tblLogin 
            WHERE [Username] = @prm_UserName and 
                  [Password] = @prm_Password -- password is a keyword, wrap it in []";

       //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using 
       using (com = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_UserName", login);
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Password", password);  

         //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
         using (var dr = com.ExecuteReader()) {
           return dr.Read(); // do we have at least one record?
         }
       } 
     }
   }
```

UI:

```
   private void btnexit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     if (TryLogin(txtusername.Text, txtpassword.Text)) {
       frmHome Home = new frmHome();
       Home.Show();
       this.Hide();
     }
     else { 
       MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username or/and Password");
       txtusername.Clear();
       txtpassword.Clear();

       if (txtusername.CanFocus) 
         txtusername.Focus();  
     }
   }
```